# Dynamic Range In Gsheet - Preparing GForm data before analysis

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So I am working on Google Form Data in Gsheet and I would like to finish my macro in order to have exploitable data.

My google form response in Gsheet are drooped following this format:

Timestamp | Email Address | Reporter | Group | Month | Year | Question1 | tagQ1 | Question2 | SeverityLevel Q2 | tagQ2

I would like to automate a script so that they appear like this :

Year | Month | Group | Question (1 and then 2) | Tags (Q1 and then Q2) | SeverityLevel (empty if Q1 info if Q2) | Reporter

Such as ...
2020 / 02 / group1 / response1 / tag1 / null / reporter1
2020 / 02 / group1 / response2 / tag2 / severity2 / reporter1

Until now I have created a first script (I am a beginner) :

```js
function TableGeneratorTest() {
    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var TableSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Table");
    var FormSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
    var NumObs = FormSheet.getLastRow();
    //In a first part we are going to copy past Year(F) Month(E) Group(D) Question1(G) TagQ1(H) Reporter(C)  
    FormSheet.getRange("F2:F12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(2, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
    FormSheet.getRange("E2:E12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(2, 2), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
    FormSheet.getRange("D2:D12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(2, 3), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
    FormSheet.getRange("G2:G12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(2, 4), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
    FormSheet.getRange("H2:H12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(2, 6), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
    FormSheet.getRange("C2:C12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(2, 8), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
    //Then we are going to increment the Year,Month,Group with Question2(M) TagQ2(O) Severity level(N) and Reporter(C)  
    FormSheet.getRange("F2:F12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(1 + NumObs, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
    FormSheet.getRange("E2:E12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(1 + NumObs, 2), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
    FormSheet.getRange("D2:D12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(1 + NumObs, 3), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
    FormSheet.getRange("M2:M12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(1 + NumObs, 4), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
    FormSheet.getRange("O2:O12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(1 + NumObs, 6), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
    FormSheet.getRange("N2:N12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(1 + NumObs, 7), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
    FormSheet.getRange("C2:C12").copyTo(TableSheet.getRange(1 + NumObs, 8), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
        false);
}
```

This first attempt works, but I would like to automate it, for example in NumObs I know that I have 12 lines, and in the .getRange method I would like to specify the number of observation such as :

```
.getRange("C2:C"&NumObs)
```

Doesn't seems to work, any idea how to deal with it please?

Thanks!

Comment: try `.getRange("C2:C"+NumObs)`

Comment: so simple lol, thanks a lot Marios!

Comment: Actually you should use `.getRange("C2:C"+NumObs-1)` since you starting on the second row

Comment: @Cooper nice catch ;). I will upvote if you post it as an answer Cooper :)

Comment: @Cooper Could you formalise your comment that solved the user's problem into an answer so that other users with similar issues can easily find an answer? Thanks ! :D